# Removing word from regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which can has a value like,

```
my $str = "auth_plugin_stack = a,b,EXT::USCC::USCCAuth,c,d"; # should return auth_plugin_stack = a,b,c,d
```

I want to have a regex to remove the word 'EXT::USCC::USCCAuth'.

The $str can have following values also.

```
my $str = "auth_plugin_stack = EXT::USCC::USCCAuth"; # should return auth_plugin_stack = 
my $str = "auth_plugin_stack = a,b,EXT::USCC::USCCAuth"; # should return auth_plugin_stack = a,b
my $str = "auth_plugin_stack = EXT::USCC::USCCAuth,c,d"; # should return auth_plugin_stack = c,d
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXT::USCC::USCCAuth,?|,?EXT::USCC::USCCAuth
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/42